# Extension of an automorphism to its predual

Tags: operator-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

Let $M$ is a von Neumann algebra equipped with state $\varphi$ , $\alpha$ $\in$ $Aut(M)$ preserving state $\varphi$, then does $\alpha$ extends to $\alpha_{1}:L^{1}(M,\varphi)\rightarrow L^{1}(M, \varphi)$?

Comment: The answer is yes if the automorphism is normal. Which i think is automatic if $\varphi$ is normal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The space L$^1(M,φ)$ is independent of the choice of the weight φ.
It is known as the predual of M, and is also denoted by $M_*$.

In Sakai's approach to von Neumann algebras,
von Neumann algebras are defined as C*-algebras that admit a predual
and morphisms of von Neumann algebras are defined as morphisms of C*-algebras that
admit a predual.
So the answer to your question is tautologically true.
See Sakai's book “[C*-algebras and W*-algebras](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-642-61993-9)”.